# How to monitor public ip and the location(country, state, city) simultaneously in terminal

Tags: networking, server, internet, ip

I am trying to monitor my public ip and the location. I found some command which could help me to find what is my public ip but I could not find any command which can tell me the location( Country, state, city ) simultaneously. Could any one can give me and idea how to monitor them at the same time in terminal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## ipinfo.io

You could try **ipinfo.io** online service. **ipinfo.io** provides a JSON-based geolocation API.

Try this :

```
curl ipinfo.io
```

Here is an example of the output returned :

```
{
  "ip": "84.215.115.185",
  "hostname": "snf-86437.vm.okeanos.grnet.gr",
  "city": "Athens",
  "region": "Attiki",
  "country": "GR",
  "loc": "37.9833,23.7333",
  "org": "AS5408 Greek Research and Technology Network S.A"
}
```

---

## GeoIP

Now you can install GeoIP, which is a C library that enables you to find the country that any IP address or hostname originates from. It uses a file-based database.

First, you need to install

> geoip-database-contrib
>
> This package contains a script that downloads the latest version of
>   the binary flavor of the four MaxMind GeoLite databases (Country, IPv6
>   Country, City, and ASN).

Execute this command to install the package

```
sudo apt-get install geoip-database-contrib
```

After this command is executed, it installs a cron job that will update the GeoLite databases. It is located at

```
/etc/cron.d/geoip-database-contrib
```

So since this installed the required file based databases, if we want to use the command line tool like geoiplookup, we have to install another package. This package is called geoip-bin. Execute

```
sudo apt-get install geoip-bin
```

Now you can execute the command

```
geoiplookup google.com
```

Here is an example of the output returned from the tool.

```
GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 1: US, CA, Mountain View, 94043, 37.419201, -122.057404, 807, 650
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 0: US, CA, Mountain View, 94043, 37.419201, -122.057404
GeoIP ASNum Edition: AS15169 Google Inc.
```

To execute this command with your server's IP type :

```
geoiplookup $(curl ipv4.icanhazip.com)
```

---

#### Note :

It should be noted that you do not own your IP address – your ISP or service provider does. Thus, all public information about that IP address will in all likelihood refer only to them.

[Source](http://www.whiletrueconsulting.com/how-to-install-geoip-on-ubuntu-12-04/)

Comment: Sorry, but you can not get `country that any IP address or hostname originates from`. It's wrong answer. Only can you get is address of ip address is registered. Data from RIPE, APNIC ... You can not get location of user based on ip address.

Comment: Thank you very much.. I used the curl ipinfo.io . It could not find the city, and state but still it can find the ip, the hostname and the country.. .. ;) :D

Comment: @2707974 Thanks for the hint. I forgot to mention it. Post updated.

Answer (score 2):

Using the command below and a little bit JSON:

First install `jq` – a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

Now start the command below to get the fonformation for your public IP

```
curl --silent ipinfo.io | jq -r '.country,.region,.city'
```

---

Example for a specific IP address instead of your public IP

```
$ curl --silent ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8 | jq -r '.country,.region,.city'
US
California
Mountain View
```

Answer (score 1):

Mission, almost, impossible. Your ip belong to your ISP and you can see only data of ISP registration aka ISP Street name.  Nearer data you can only get if you register some net range at [RIPE](https://www.ripe.net/), but steel you can not get exact data like street name etc.

If you use dynamic public net range from ISP you will always see ISP data or shared hosting or ...

Example:

```
host askubuntu.com
```

reslove logical name to ip

```
askubuntu.com has address 104.16.15.44
askubuntu.com has address 104.16.18.44
askubuntu.com has address 104.16.16.44
askubuntu.com has address 104.16.19.44
askubuntu.com has address 104.16.17.44
```

then ask whois owner

```
whois 104.16.15.44


#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# http://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#


#
# The following results may also be obtained via:
# http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=104.16.15.44?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&showNonArinTopLevelNet=false&ext=netref2
#

NetRange:       104.16.0.0 - 104.31.255.255
CIDR:           104.16.0.0/12
NetName:        CLOUDFLARENET
NetHandle:      NET-104-16-0-0-1
Parent:         NET104 (NET-104-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Assignment
OriginAS:       AS13335
Organization:   CloudFlare, Inc. (CLOUD14)
RegDate:        2014-03-28
Updated:        2014-03-28
Comment:        https://www.cloudflare.com
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-104-16-0-0-1



OrgName:        CloudFlare, Inc.
OrgId:          CLOUD14
Address:        665 Third Street #207
City:           San Francisco
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     94107
Country:        US
RegDate:        2010-07-09
Updated:        2013-01-04
Comment:        http://www.cloudflare.com/
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/CLOUD14


OrgTechHandle: ADMIN2521-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Admin
OrgTechPhone:  +1-650-319-8930 
OrgTechEmail:  admin@cloudflare.com
OrgTechRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ADMIN2521-ARIN

OrgAbuseHandle: ABUSE2916-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Abuse
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-650-319-8930 
OrgAbuseEmail:  abuse@cloudflare.com
OrgAbuseRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ABUSE2916-ARIN

OrgNOCHandle: NOC11962-ARIN
OrgNOCName:   NOC
OrgNOCPhone:  +1-650-319-8930 
OrgNOCEmail:  noc@cloudflare.com
OrgNOCRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/NOC11962-ARIN


#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# http://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#
```

For any ip from `NetRange:       104.16.0.0 - 104.31.255.255` you will see the same Street `Address:        665 Third Street #207`

Example 2:

```
whois 104.16.17.50

#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# http://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#


#
# The following results may also be obtained via:
# http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=104.16.17.50?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&showNonArinTopLevelNet=false&ext=netref2
#

NetRange:       104.16.0.0 - 104.31.255.255
CIDR:           104.16.0.0/12
NetName:        CLOUDFLARENET
NetHandle:      NET-104-16-0-0-1
Parent:         NET104 (NET-104-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Assignment
OriginAS:       AS13335
Organization:   CloudFlare, Inc. (CLOUD14)
RegDate:        2014-03-28
Updated:        2014-03-28
Comment:        https://www.cloudflare.com
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-104-16-0-0-1



OrgName:        CloudFlare, Inc.
OrgId:          CLOUD14
Address:        665 Third Street #207
City:           San Francisco
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     94107
Country:        US
RegDate:        2010-07-09
Updated:        2013-01-04
Comment:        http://www.cloudflare.com/
Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/org/CLOUD14


OrgTechHandle: ADMIN2521-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Admin
OrgTechPhone:  +1-650-319-8930 
OrgTechEmail:  admin@cloudflare.com
OrgTechRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ADMIN2521-ARIN

OrgAbuseHandle: ABUSE2916-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Abuse
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-650-319-8930 
OrgAbuseEmail:  abuse@cloudflare.com
OrgAbuseRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ABUSE2916-ARIN

OrgNOCHandle: NOC11962-ARIN
OrgNOCName:   NOC
OrgNOCPhone:  +1-650-319-8930 
OrgNOCEmail:  noc@cloudflare.com
OrgNOCRef:    http://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/NOC11962-ARIN


#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# http://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
```